# Getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException intermittently for repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

In my project I have created a repository interface by implementing CrudRepository. My underlying DB is Cassandra. I am intermittently getting below error and my application is failing to start -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userHelper': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.org.retail.userops.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

There are other repository interfaces which are working fine.

My spring boot app -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.org.retail")
@EnableCassandraRepositories( basePackages = { "com.org.retail.userops.repository" })
public class UserApplication {

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args
     *            the arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * Rest template.
     *
     * @param builder
     *            the builder
     * @return the rest template
     */
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate( RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

This is UserRepository interface -

```
package com.org.retail.userops.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.org.retail.userops.domain.User;

    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

        @Query( "select * from user where userid=?0 and userstatus IN (?1)")
        List<User> findByUserIdAndUserStatus( String userId, List<String> statusList);
    }
```

Sometimes application is getting up and sometimes not, so its weird. I am suspecting if there is any Cassandra error while loading repository. Is there any way to see sql errors in startup in spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Repository` (or `@Service` or `@Component`) on top of UserRepository class, It might fix the issue.

But if the issue is only intermittent, then there might be some connectivity issues with cassandra DB from you local machine.

To see what queries are going, add these in `application.properties` file

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

To see what spring is doing behind the scenes or at startup, add this:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

Comment: Thanks. Other repository interfaces does not have Repository (or Service or Component) annotations. I am wondering how they are working. I will try with these logging properties to see if I am getting some sql error.

Comment: Add the code for class with main method. Is there any config class for configuring cassandra connection?, if yes, please add that code too